# ActiveMQ: how to set dead letter strategy on client side?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm implementing the unsent messages handling but there is an issue.
The dead letter stratagy can be set on server-side in cofiguration file (by queue name pattern), but queues for my messages are created dynamically and their names are unknown on configuration stage.
So I wonder if it is possible to set dead letter strategy from the client-side?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want, but according to [this](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html), you should be able to use a wildcard `>` in your config with the `IndividualDeadLetterStrategy` so each of your queues gets its own DLQ.  See this part:

> You can apply this strategy using wild card if you like so that all
>   queues get their own dead-letter queue, as is shown in the example
>   below.

```
<broker...>
  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <!-- Set the following policy on all queues using the '>' wildcard -->
        <policyEntry queue=">">
          <deadLetterStrategy>
            <!--
              Use the prefix 'DLQ.' for the destination name, and make
              the DLQ a queue rather than a topic
            -->
            <individualDeadLetterStrategy
              queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true" />
```

Comment: There is no way to set it on the client side, this is the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](http://www.mulesoft.org/mule-activemq-integration-examples), you will find an example of how to configure it, this is an extract:

```
<spring:bean id="AmqDeadLetterStrategy"
    class="org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.IndividualDeadLetterStrategy"
                     p:queuePrefix="DLQ." />

<spring:bean id="AmqDefaultPolicyEntry"
                     class="org.apache.activemq.broker.region.policy.PolicyEntry"
                     p:queue="jobs.*"
                     p:deadLetterStrategy-ref="AmqDeadLetterStrategy" />
```